# How to pass unknown query parameters in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm building an Angular application for my existing Node.js backend. In my Node.js backend I am getting the data from an API which has two query parameters, `accountId` and `apiKey` which can obviously each time be different. The url for my backend application looks like this: http://localhost:3000/export?accountId=23&apiKey=55. So in my Angular application, in the service I need to pass this URL which is called in the backend to be able to show the data which i get in the backend but I'm not sure how.. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or a small example would be helpful.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetMessagesService {

  message: any;
  uri: string = 'http://localhost:3000/export';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



  getCannedMessages() {
    return this.http.get('uri');
  }
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetMessagesService } from './get-messages.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
  providers: [ GetMessagesService ]
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private gms: GetMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  showCannedMessages() {
    this.gms.getCannedMessages()
    .subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like this:

```
getCannedMessages(accountId: number, apiKey: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.uri, {params: {accountId, apiKey}})
}
```

```
  showCannedMessages() {
    const accountId = getAccountIdSomehow();
    const apiKey = getApiKeySomehow();

    this.gms.getCannedMessages(accountId, apiKey)
    .subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Stackblitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h2f3fe?file=src/app/joke.service.ts

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear... The url is just an example of how the url can look like but the parameters can be different

Comment: @sufocator sorry I thought it was obvious you just make them parameters of your function, edited to be more clear